# Referencing individual figures in minipage

Tags: subfloats, ieeetran

I have a two column article and multiple figures. I tried to use {figure*} command but it occupies the whole horizontal line even with two small images ([image: {figure*} problem]), and no more images, that is another {figure*}, can be drawn on the same line. I then used {minipage} environment that solved the matter (figure attached)[image: {minipage}] but individual figures are not referenceabl now. A specimen for required figure placement is attached here. [image: Required figure placement]. The code for {minipage} is

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.47\linewidth]{image1}
        \label{label1}}
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.47\linewidth]{image2}
        \label{label2}}
        \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-12pt}
    \caption{caption}
        \label{Label1}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.47\linewidth]{image3}
        \label{label3}}\quad
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.47\linewidth]{image4}
        \label{label4}}
        \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-16pt}
        \caption{caption}
        \label{Label2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{.48\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.47\linewidth]{iamge5}
        \label{label5}}\quad
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.47\linewidth]{image6}
        \label{label6}}
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.47\linewidth]{image7}
        \label{label7}}\quad
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=.47\linewidth]{image8}
        \label{label8}}
        \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-16pt}
        \caption{caption2}
        \label{Label3}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Kindly note that in the specimen figure, individual figures are referenceable. Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the `IEEEtran` manual? "1)  Subfigures:"  in page 10 explains and shows how to use the `subfig` package to get a figure environment with multiple referencable subfigures.

Comment: Please note that the documentation also clearly states, that "sub-caption.sty package can not be recommended at this time because it does not provide an option to prevent the underlying caption.sty  from  taking  control  of  main  caption  formatting away from IEEEtran" Also: "caption.sty, which, in its default con-figuration,  will  overrride  IEEEtran’s  handling  of  captions—resulting  in  non-IEEE  style  main  captions."

Comment: Regarding: "I tried to use {figure*} command but it occupies the whole horizontal line even with two small images ": This is the expected behaviour of the `figure*` environment. `figure` in the other hand is only as wide as a single column while `figure*` always spans both columns.

Comment: you should remove the minipage here, they are doing nothing other than force .48\textwidth as an approximation to `\columnwidth`

Answer (score 2):

To quote from the [`IEEEtran` user manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran):

> Subfigures  can  be  obtain  via  the  use  of Steven Douglas Cochran’s `subfigure` [23] or `subfig` [24] packages.   Be  forewarned   that   the   former   is   no   longer   being maintained and, although self-contained and compatible with `IEEEtran`, is becoming incompatible with an increasing number  of  other  LATEX  packages  including  `fixltx2e.sty`.  For  this reason,  `subfigure.sty`  is  not  recommended  for  new  work  and will not be covered here. [...] Axel  Sommerfeldt’s  modern  and  actively  maintained  `sub-caption.sty` package [25] can not be recommended at this time because it does not provide an option to prevent the underlying `caption.sty`  from  taking  control  of  main  caption formatting away from `IEEEtran`.

The **package of choice** is therefore **`subfig`** as opposed to `subcaption` and `caption` that you loaded in the code in your question.

Following the further advice on page 10 of the above mentioned manual, one can obtain the following MWE:

I have used the `figure` environment here. This will only be as wide as one of the two columns. The `figure*` environment will on the other hand span both columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\subfloat[subfigure's caption]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image}
\label{fig_first_subfigure}}
\hfil
\subfloat[second subfigure's caption]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image}
\label{fig_second_subfigure}}
\caption{Caption for the whole figure}
\label{fig_complete}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig_first_subfigure}

\ref{fig_second_subfigure}

\ref{fig_complete}

\end{document}
```